# adding pointer to integer in C

Tags: c, pointers, integer

In the following segment of code:

```
if (buffer  + strlen(buffer) >= len -1) beep();
```

note: `len` is an `int`, `buffer` is a pointer to `char`.

I don't understand how would someone add buffer (a pointer) to the `strlen()` of a string and compare it to `len`. Can any one please help me. 
note: the actual code link is http://www.finseth.com/craft/#intro.1.4
any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the line of code in the 'if' statement is nonsence.  suggest:  ''if( strlen(buffer) > (len-1)) beep(); '   However, by the time this condition is 'true', the buffer would be past the end of the 'text' literal, resulting in undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: note that the 'if' statement is depending heavily on the presidence of the C operators.  It would be much clearer to humans if another set or two of parens were incorporated.

Comment: @user3629249 it's common knowledge that arithmetic operators have higher precedence than relational, I doubt anyone looks at this and thinks it might be `buffer + (strlen(buffer) >= len) - 1`

Comment: To me the code at that side looks somewhat ouitdated, but that might be due to the (nowadays) uncommon formatting. For the line in question, I would suspect some pre-ANSI (aka K&R) hacks or a mixture. Anyway it is non-standard and even if len was a proper pointer, it's name is not really self-explanatory (for instance, it would have to point to the same array). With that line, I would be really careful on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is illegal. A pointer may not be compared to an integer (other than a constant `0`). The compiler should have generated an error message.

Some compilers may generate "only" a warning in the default configuration, and perform a nonsensical comparison at runtime, but you should treat this as an error.

You could report this bug to the author of this page; although if basic compilation errors get through their QA process I hate to think what other mistakes might also be present.

Answer (score 0):

It's called pointer arithmetic, it's essentially the same as

```
if (&buffer[strlen(buffer)] >= len - 1)
```

which is a very ugly line of code in both versions.

Why do they compare it to `len - 1` is a mistery, unless `len` is overwritten from the initial value, or the programmer knows exactly what the address of `"text"` is, which would depend on the compiler AFAIK.

Comment: would you please take a look to the actual code? it is from a book named the craft of text editing and the link to the code is: http://www.finseth.com/craft/#intro.1.4

Comment: In addition to being ugly, it's also a bug. `buffer + strlen(buffer)` is a pointer, but it's being compared to the integer `len - 1`, which is unlikely to result in anything meaningful.